# How to select dropdown if it is not have id and label in selenium

Tags: selenium

Here is my HTML

```
    <option ng-selected="user.id == userDetail.assignedTo.id" ng-repeat="user in assignableUsers | orderBy:user.name" value="9,5304" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                            User1
                        </option>
<option ng-selected="user.id == userDetail.assignedTo.id" ng-repeat="user in assignableUsers | orderBy:user.name" value="19,5304" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                            User2
                        </option>
```

It has list of dropdown values. I wanted to select say eg., User2.

If I give select by Label is not working since it does not have label and 
value also it has id not text (which is dynamic number build to build).

Only option is selectByIndex by 2. If incase, User11 exists then it takes User11 as the dropdown list orders by alpahbetically ascending..

I have option to take getText for Each Index and match it User2 then select that index.. Is that only way or any other solution?

Comment: There should be a method to selectOptionByVisibleText, so you can choose option by `"User2"`. as you didn't specify a programming language you use, it's hard to tell how exactly your code should looks like...

Comment: Thats very good idea..Thank you